# Trying to use Javascript to hide an element if a page has a vertical scroll-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide and element with an id of #myWork if and only if the page (html, body) has a vertical scroll-bar.
After reading another question/answer on detecting vertical scroll-bar presence, I have the following code:

```
var hasVScroll = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
        var cStyle = document.body.currentStyle||window.getComputedStyle(document.body, "");
        hasVScroll = cStyle.overflow == "visible" || cStyle.overflowY == "visible" || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflow == "auto") || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflowY == "auto");
        if(hasVScroll){
            document.getElementById('myWork').style.display = 'none';
        }
```

This works, but it also hides the element with an id of myWork when there isn't a vertical scroll-bar on this html page.

I would sincerely appreciate any and all help getting this right.

P.S. I tried hiding it with jQuery inside the if-statement since I'm already using jQuery, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, if it is hiding the element that means that probably `cStyle.overflow == "visible" || cStyle.overflowY == "visible"` evaluates to true. So this might be related to your CSS? If not, have you tested this on all browsers? I wouldn't be surprised if the first line is not cross-browser.

Comment: @bellpeace I don't think its a CSS issue, because the site is fine when scripts are turned off. I've only tested it in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're already using jQuery, this should work:

```
function init(e){
    var hasVScroll = $(document).height( ) > $(window).height( );

    if(hasVScroll){
        $('#myWork').hide( );
    }

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

ok, so the reason its not working is this

```
var cStyle = document.body.currentStyle||window.getComputedStyle(document.body, "");
hasVScroll = cStyle.overflow == "visible" || cStyle.overflowY == "visible" || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflow == "auto") || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflowY == "auto");
```

is always setting hasVScroll to true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, okay so the logic was wrong and it was always resulting in true?
That makes sense why it was always working.

Ah, I see what you did. I didn't think of the difference between document being the whole document and window just being the current window / viewport. 
Thank you.

Comment: here is a way you can test the above in chrome: press CTRL+SHIFT+J to bring up the console, paste in the two lines above (the ones setting cStyle and hasVScroll) and hit enter -- it should produce true.  Its always true because cStyle.overflow and cStyle.overflowY both default to "visible" on the body.